# MySQL - How to get all the results having all of the column values?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, relational-division

I want to get all of the id1 where id2 is equal to **2 and 3**. Consider the sample table given below

**Sample Table-**

```
| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
|  1  |  2  |
|  1  |  3  |
|  1  |  4  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  4  |
```

In this case, expected output is as mentioned below because **2 is only mapped to 2 and not to 3**, and hence only 1 result comes in output.

**Expected output-**

```
| id1 |
| --- |
|  1  |
```

But when i run the following query  it also gives id1 = 2 in result along with id1 = 1

```
Select id1 from table where id2 in (2,3) group by id1;
```

What is the correct query to get this output?

Comment: try this: Select id1 from table where id in (select id from table where id2 in (2,3)), dont have a sql server right now I cannot test my sql, but you can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `HAVING` to filter the data

```
Select id1,count(distinct id2) from table 
 where id2 in (2,3) 
 group by id1 having count(distinct id2) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation, we can try:

```sql
SELECT id1
FROM yourTable
WHERE id2 IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY id1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id2) = 2;
```

Comment: @ShubhamSingal Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should consider _accepting_ one of the 2 answers given here, if they resolved your problem, by clicking the green checkmark.